# Issues with triggering a function on __get and __set

Tags: php

## Update

I've come to a solution based on duskwuff's answer. He did answer the question I asked. This is here for anyone in the future - mainly myself.

As he mentioned the issued lied in `$this->{$key} = $val;`

I have updated the `__constructor` to assign the values to the protected attribute `$attributes` rather than the object itself which allows `__get` and `__set` to be triggered properly.

I have left the rest of the code untouched.

---

I've recently started working on a new project I am unfamiliar with so bear with me. We have custom classes written to fetch records from MongoDB and Sql Server. All Sql Server and Mongo models will eventually extend the `Model` class with their respective `MongoModel` and `MsSqlModel` classes in between.

Ex: `Vendor extends MongoModel` > `MongoModel extends DatabaseModel` > `DatabaseModel extends Model`

```
class Model implements JsonSerializable, IteratorAggregate {
   ...
   public function __construct($attributes = []) {
       foreach ( $attributes as $key => $val )
           $this->{$key} = $val;
   }
   ...
   public function &__get($key) {
       if ( $this->isPrivateKey($key) ) {
          return $this->$key;
       } else {
          return $this->attributes[$key];
       }
   }

   public function __set($key, $value) {
       if ( $this->isPrivateKey($key) ) {
           $this->$key = $value;
       } else {
           $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
       }
   }
   ...
}
```

For testing purposes I've included the `Cryptarch` class and the `Encryptable` class in the `Vendor` model file. `Cryptarch` only has two functions `encrypt` and `decrypt` - If needed I can post them but they're nothing special as I am not a security expert.

```
trait Encryptable {

    public function &__get($key) {

        $value = parent::__get($key);

        if ( in_array($key, $this->encryptable) ) {
            return Cryptarch::decrypt($value);
        }

        return $value;

    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {

        if ( in_array($key, $this->encryptable) ) {
            $value = Cryptarch::encrypt($value);
        }

        parent::__set($key, $value);

    }

}

class Vendor extends MongoModel
{
    use Encryptable;

    protected $encryptable = [
        'ssn'
    ];
    ...
}
```

With that out of the way, I am trying to automatically encrypt/decrypt sensitive information when a model's attribute is being set(encrypt) or get(decrypt).

On my page, I am simply loading the record I want to test on:
`$res = Vendor::load('myid');`
If I `var_dump($res->ssn)` I get the **encrypted** value instead of the **decrypted** value.

If I set the value `$res->ssn = 'somethingelse';` and `var_dump($res->ssn)` it outputs `string(13) "somethingelse"`.

**However**, if I remove the `__set` function from `Encryptable` and attempt to output `$res->ssn` I get the properly decrypted value.

If I `var_dump` the parameter in `Cryptarch::decrypt($val)` I get the correct value from the DB(encrypted) - but if I try to `var_dump` the 'decrypted' result and `exit;` from the decrypt function it returns the encrypted value not `bool(false)` like `openssl_decrypt` should return if it fails. If I override (`$val = 'encryptedstring';`) the param in decrypt with the direct value from the DB and `var_dump` the decrypted result it works fine.

Now, the rest of the page/site works with `Vendor` using the `Encryptable` trait. I can still set values and save them and fetch them etc. The only thing that is causing a hang up is attempting to decrypt the value returns the same value instead of `bool(false)` like `openssl_decrypt` should, if it fails, and setting a value does not encrypt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a limitation of PHP -- the `__get` and `__set` magic functions only fire when an attribute is accessed which doesn't exist on the object. They are never called for attributes that exist.

Your implementation of `__set` includes:

```
$this->$key = $value;
```

which could be setting attributes on the object. Any attribute that has been created this way will no longer call the `__get` or `__set` methods.

Comment: So, then what is the best approach for automatically checking if the attribute/data I want needs to be encrypted/decrypted? I am kind of at a loss. Originally I had setup an additional function on the `Model` class to encrypt/decrypt a column/attribute but it seemed like I could do better by removing the extra step.

Comment: My inclination would be to perform the encryption/decryption when storing/loading the object to/from the database, not when accessing the field.